# WPF Datagrid VERY SLOW

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rendering

i am using a datagrid to display a datatable which contains ~50 rows. For some reason the rendering of the grid is very slow, i takes ~ 2sec to display the grid with the data. If I use a ListBox or a ListView for example the rendering is way faster, which means no delay at all. 
The datatable i want to display has 20 columns, but also if i want to display only one column it has no effect on the rendering performance.

That's the code i am using to display the grid:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

if I set autogeneratecolumns to false (the grid renders the rows but no columns), the grid still needs ~2sec to render

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

if i use a listbox instead it has no delay at all (but i need to write a generic template to display all the columns), also ListView has no delays at all

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
```

I have no idea why the grid is that slow. I have also tried to set VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" but it had no effect on performance.

Any ideas?

KR Manuel

Comment: Are you sure it's the rendering takes time and not getting the data, building the datagrid etc?

Comment: I am pretty sure, as the listbox or listview has no delay at all using the same binding.

Comment: Share some code on how you populate the bound data source and how you raise property change notification etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL DataGrid's are horrendously slow (even the ones you pay for). You need to turn on virtualization. `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = true` as well as `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = recycling`. If you have a lot of columns, or start to do templates, it'll slow to a crawl again. Nothing you can do about that really. I've tried every DataGrid out there (syncfusion, infragistics, etc). They are all very slow.

Comment: The trick is to pump the data to the grid using a delegate and setting it's priority to `Background`.